# UVM: illegal combination of driver and procedural assignment warning

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have a UVM testbench for a small block in my chip.  In this there is an agent with a driver that drives data on a virtual interface which looks something like this:

```
interface my_if (input bit clk);

  logic [3:0] opcode;

  // Clocking block for the driver
  clocking drvClk @(posedge clk);
    output opcode;
  endclocking

  // Clocking block for the monitor      
  clocking monClk @(posedge clk);
    input opcode;
  endclocking

endinterface
```

I use this interface in my driver like this:

```
class my_driver extends uvm_driver #(my_tr);
  my_if vif;
  ...
  virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.run_phase(phase);

    forever begin
      seq_item_port.get_next_item(req);

      // Drive the transaction onto the interface
      // and wait for next clock
      vif.opcode <= req.opcode;
      @(vif.drvClk);

      seq_item_port.item_done();
    end
  endtask
endclass
```

As far as i can tell, this is the recommended way of doing things, and it works well.  The problem arises when I integrate this agent into a higher level testbench.  In that case the agent is now passive and the driver is not built.  I am assigning the opcode value to the interface so the monitor can observe it.  Here is a snippet of my top level wire harness:

```
module my_top();
  bit clk = 0;

  always #5 clk = !clk;

  // instantiate the interface
  my_if my_if_inst(.clk(clk));

  // instantiate my dut
  my_dut dut(...);

  // pull out the internal opcode signal and assign it
  // to the interface
  assign my_if_inst.opcode = dut.submodule.opcode;

  // Set the virtual interface inside the agent
  initial begin
    uvm_config_db#(virtual my_if)::set(uvm_root::get(),"uvm_test_top.tb.env.my_agent", "vif", my_if_inst);
  end 
endmodule
```

When I run this in NC I get a warning:

```
ncelab: *W,ICPAVW: Illegal combination of driver and procedural assignment to variable opcode detected (output clockvar found in clocking block)
```

This makes sense since the interface defines this signal as an output for the drvClk block and I am doing an assignment at the top level.  I can just ignore this warning (the code works just fine) but I would rather code it in a way that it runs cleanly.  What is the recommended way to do this?  I got rid of the clocking block for the driver and that works, but I think I am setting myself up for race conditions if I do that.

Comment: I happened to encounter a similar issue. Surprisingly VCS did not have any issues compiling the same code but Incisive did. @dave_59's answer is accurate. There's an override [switch](https://community.cadence.com/cadence_technology_forums/f/functional-verification/40909/elaboration-error-icdpav-on-xcelium) in Incisive for this though, not sure why

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy; make opcode a `wire` in your interface.

Treat opcode the same as you would a bidirectional signal. See my [DVCon paper](http://events.dvcon.org/2012/proceedings/papers/01P_3.pdf) on this subject.

Comment: Well, that did the trick.  I had just copied the examples which used 'logic' for everything and never questioned it.  I assumed that since I was doing a non-blocking assignment in the driver that a wire wouldn't be legal.  In my head "<=" means "you must have logic or reg here!".  Thanks for making my first stackoverflow experience a quick one!

Comment: Thanks Dave, The document makes sense. However I've a problem at reset condition, generally driver is written to drive interface signals instead of clocking block signals at reset. How do I tackle reset condition in driver?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid declaring _reg and then assigning signal = signal_reg, is there any other/better way to do this? (can't edit comment after 5 minutes so a new comment)

Comment: There's no need to drive signals asynchronously for the general testcase at reset. You may want to build s special testcase to handle asynchronous timing issues.