# How to initialize clocking block signals at reset

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I've been reading through [UVM: illegal combination of driver and procedural assignment warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249860/uvm-illegal-combination-of-driver-and-procedural-assignment-warning) and paper attached in answer. 
(Please consider paper linked in the question mentioned)

However drivers are implemented to drive reset values on interface signals instead of on clocking block signals, the clock is not guaranteed to be running at reset.

So how can I go about this scenario if interface signals are declared wires.

for e.g.
consider the code in linked question. General scenario would be

```
@(vif.cb); 
vif.cb.opcode <= value;
```

This is correct even if opcode is declared net in interface cause clocking block will take care of correct assignment. However I can't say

```
@(vif.rst);
vif.cb.opcode <= init_value;
```

since I can't guarantee clock at reset. To accommodate this I'll have to change clock generation strategy.

Neither can I say

```
 vif.opcode <= init_value;
```

cause its illegal to use procedural assignment with net type signals

The other way is gating signals declared as net with reset but I think for that I'll have to declare temporary signals in interface. Can anyone elaborate how can I achieve driving nets at reset ?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to be more specific here. Show the code that is causing you problems.

Comment: I hope now question elaborates correctly let me know if I should add more details, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's illegal to assign nets from procedural code, it's legal to force values onto them. You can do the following:

```
@(negedge vif.rst);
force vif.opcode = 0;
```

Bonus: IMO you shouldn't have `opcode` defined as a wire. The illegal combination of procedural and continuous driver warning is wrong. The SV 2012 standard clearly states in **14.16.2 Driving clocking output signals**:

> It is possible to use a procedural assignment to assign to a signal associated with an output clockvar. When
>   the associated signal is a variable, the procedural assignment assigns a new value to the variable, and the
>   variable shall hold that value until another assignment occurs (either from a drive to a clocking block output
>   or another procedural assignment).

Comment: so we are basically waiting for tools to update and accommodate the SV 2012 standard. For now I'll use force on interface nets accordingly and try to create another branch with logic signals so we have correct functionality. Thanks

Comment: @wisemonkey Actually, I tried it out with `logic` and it works without the warning. The warning in the question you linked must have come from somewhere else (the setup wasn't exactly the same as it had a clocking block and a continuous assign).

Comment: @wisemonkey But w.r.t. waiting to accommodate the standard, this is true. I don't think any tool has implemented 100% of it.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out, The code I'm using is not exactly same. However it is similar situation and I get the warning with Incisive, I should try it with latest Questa and see what happens.